# How to keep run a game in window while we are inputting in terminal python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, turtle-graphics

I am new to python programming i was writing a code of snake game in which snake moves randomly on x axis. And user have to put input in terminal for the location of food and poison on x axis. And snake must be inside the food and poison.

"The main thing i want to that is while the user input any location of food and Poison the snake must move whole time without stopping"

I will be thankful to you if you provide me something that can help or do make some changes in the code given below

Thanks

```
import random
import turtle
import time
delay = 0.1
score = 0
s=0
#setting up screen
win = turtle.Screen()
win.title("Snake Game")
win.bgcolor("black")
win.setup(height= 480, width=480)
win.tracer(0)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#------------------------------------------------SNAKE-----------------------------------------------------------------
head = turtle.Turtle()
head.speed(0)
head.shape("square")
head.color("white")
head.penup()
head.goto(0,0)
head.direction = "stop"

# FOOD
f = int(input("Enter location of food on x-axis :"))
poi = int(input("Enter location of poison on x-axis :"))
if  poi == 0 and f == 0 or poi == f:
    poi = poi + 40
    f = f + 30
if poi <=0 and f <= 0:
    poi = -poi
if poi >=0 and f >=0:
    f = -f


food = turtle.Turtle()
food.speed(0)
food.shape("circle")
food.color("green")
food.penup()
food.goto(int(f),0)
# Poison
Poison = turtle.Turtle()
Poison.speed(0)
Poison.shape("turtle")
Poison.color("red")
Poison.penup()
Poison.goto(int(poi),0)
#------------------------------------------------SNAKE-----------------------------------------------------------------
#list
segments = []
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.shape("square")
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(-150, 205)
pen.write("Secore: 0", align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))


pen1 = turtle.Turtle()
pen1.speed(0)
pen1.shape("square")
pen1.color("white")
pen1.penup()
pen1.hideturtle()
pen1.goto(200, -226)
pen1.write("240", align="center", font=("Courier", 14, "normal"))

pen2 = turtle.Turtle()
pen2.speed(0)
pen2.shape("square")
pen2.color("white")
pen2.penup()
pen2.hideturtle()
pen2.goto(0, -226)
pen2.write("0", align="center", font=("Courier", 14, "normal"))

pen2 = turtle.Turtle()
pen2.speed(0)
pen2.shape("square")
pen2.color("white")
pen2.penup()
pen2.hideturtle()
pen2.goto(-200, -226)
pen2.write("-240", align="center", font=("Courier", 14, "normal"))
#function
def move():
    if head.direction=="up":
        head.sety(head.ycor() + 5)
    if head.direction=="down":
        head.sety(head.ycor() - 5)
    if head.direction=="left":
        head.setx(head.xcor() - 5)
    if head.direction=="right":
        head.setx(head.xcor() + 5)
def go_right():
    head.direction = "right"
def go_left():
    head.direction = "left"
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
c = 0
print("Score: ", score)
while True:
    win.update()
    l = random.randint(-220, 220)
    r = random.randint(-220, 220)
    if l>0 and l < 220:
            head.direction="right"
    if l<0 and l >-220:
            head.direction = "left"
    #check for collison with border
    if head.xcor()>230 or head.xcor()<-230 or head.ycor()>230 or head.ycor()<-230:
        time.sleep(1)
        head.goto(0,0)
        pen.clear()
        score=0
       #hidr segment
        for segment in segments:
            segment.goto(1000,1000)
        #clear segments
        segments.clear()
    #check for collision
    if head.distance(food) < 20:
       x = random.randint(-290,290)
       y = random.randint(-290,290)
       print("Food: ")
       f = int(input("enter the x axis location of food Must be in 230 to -230 "))
       if f > 230 or f < -230:
           f = input("Invalid, enter the x axis location of food Must be in 230 to -230 ")
       p = int(input("enter location of poison on x axis Must be in 230 to -230 "))



       if p > 230 or p < -230:
           p = int(input("Invalid, enter the x axis location "))
       if p == f or p ==0 and f == 0:
           p = p + 40
           f = f + 30
       if p <= 0 and f <= 0:
               p = -p
       if p >= 0 and f >= 0:
               f = -f
       if head.distance(head) < p and head.distance(head) < f:
           f = int(input("enter the location of food again snake must be inside both "))
       if head.distance(head) > f and head.distance(head) > p:
           p = int(input("enter the location of poison again snake must be inside both "))
       Poison.goto(int(p), 0)
       food.goto(int(f), 0)
       #head.direction = "stop"
       new_segment = turtle.Turtle()
       new_segment.speed(0)
       new_segment.shape("square")
       new_segment.color("grey")
       new_segment.penup()
       segments.append(new_segment)
       #increase score
       score += 10
       pen.clear()
       pen.write("Score: {}".format(score), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))
    if head.distance(Poison) < 20:
        print("Poison: ")
        p = int(input("enter location of poison on x axis Must be in -230 to -230 "))
        if p > 230 or p < -230:
           p = int(input("Invalid, enter the x axis location "))
        f = int(input("enter the x axis location of food "))
        if head.distance(head) < p and head.distance(head) < f:
            f = int(input("enter the location of food again snake must be inside both "))
        if head.distance(head) > f and head.distance(head) > p:
            p = int(input("enter the location of poison again snake must be inside both "))



        if p == f or p == 0 and f == 0:
            p = p + 40
            f = f + 30
        if p <= 0 and f <= 0:
            p = -p
        if p >= 0 and f >= 0:
            f = -f

        Poison.goto(int(p), 0)
        food.goto(int(f),0)
       # head.direction = "stop"
        # increase score

        score -= 10
        print(score)
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Score: {}".format(score), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))
    #move the end segment
    for index in range(len(segments)-1,0,-1):
        x = segments[index-1].xcor()
        y = segments[index-1].ycor()
        segments[index].goto(x+5, y-20)
     # move seg 0 to where head
    if len(segments)>0:
        segments[0].goto(head.xcor()+5, head.ycor()-20)
    move()


    time.sleep(delay)
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to do this simply, I would read a text-file rather than from the console.  If the new values read are different from the previous-read, assume they have been changed.

Something like:

```
food_x = -1
food_y = -1
...  # in main loop

try:
    # try to read the content of "user_input.txt", which we expect to be two numbers
    user_input = open( 'user_input.txt', 'rt' ).read()
    user_input = user_input.split( ' ' )             # split input into words
    user_input = list( filter( None, user_input ) )  # throw away any empty strings
    new_food_x = int( user_input[0] )
    new_food_y = int( user_input[1] )

    # We read 2 integers from the file
    # but are they different to last time?
    if ( new_food_x >= 0      and new_food_y >= 0     and
         new_food_x != food_x and new_food_y != food_y ):
        food_x = new_food_x
        food_y = new_food_y
        # TODO: whatever else is needed to flag a new food item
except:
    pass # file not found, typos, not numbers, etc.  ignore any/all errors
```

Another alternative is to read from the console in a thread, and using PyGame events `post` the result back to the main GUI thread.  This is much more involved.  I thought I answered this before, but I am unable to find it ... so maybe not.

Below is some example code which reads *stdin* in a thread, posting events back to the main thread.  This example reads numbers, or the word "quit".

```
import threading
import pygame
import enum

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH  = 200
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 200

DARK    = (  50, 50, 50 )
WHITE   = ( 255,255,255 )
RED     = ( 255, 55, 55 )
GREEN   = (   5,255, 55 )
BLUE    = (   5, 55,255 )


colour_cycle = [ DARK, WHITE, RED, GREEN, BLUE ]

# Enumerated type for messages
class UserEvents( enum.IntEnum ):
    CLIENT_NUMBER = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
    CLIENT_QUIT   = pygame.USEREVENT + 2
    # ...

# Thread function/class to handle threaded console input
class ConsoleInputThread( threading.Thread ):
    """ A thread that handles user input on the console.
        Waits for user input, then posts messages
        to the main PyGame thread for processing """
    def __init__( self, prompt ):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon         = True # exit with parent
        self.done           = False
        self.prompt         = prompt

    def stop( self ):
        self.done = True

    def run( self ):
        """ Loops until the user hangs-up """
        while ( not self.done ):
            # Get some input from the user
            user_input = input( self.prompt ).strip()
            new_event = None
            if ( user_input == 'quit' ):
                new_event = pygame.event.Event( UserEvents.CLIENT_QUIT, { } )
            else:
                try:
                    user_input = int( user_input )
                    new_event = pygame.event.Event( UserEvents.CLIENT_NUMBER, { "value":user_input } )
                except:
                    print( "Syntax Error" )
            # If we received valid input post it to the main thread
            if ( new_event ):
                pygame.event.post( new_event )



###
### MAIN
###

# Create the window
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Console Messages")
SURFACE = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE
window  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE )

# Start the connection-listener thread
input_thread = ConsoleInputThread( "Enter numbers or quit: " )
input_thread.start()

# Main paint / update / event loop
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
colour_index = 0
while ( not done ):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == UserEvents.CLIENT_QUIT ):          # from thread
            print("\nCLIENT ASKED TO QUIT " )
            done = True

        elif ( event.type == UserEvents.CLIENT_NUMBER ):         # from thread
            print( "\nVALUE WAS INPUT: %d " % ( event.value, ) )

    window.fill( colour_cycle[colour_index] )
    # rotate the colours, just so the screen changes
    colour_index += 1
    if ( colour_index >= len( colour_cycle ) ):
        colour_index = 0

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick_busy_loop(30)

input_thread.stop()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: can you please do this 2nd example with my code i am a beginner so i can understand how it works.

Comment: @RazaChishti - Please try yourself, and if it does not work, then post a question about it.  The `UserEvents`, `ConsoleInputThread` classes need to be added to your program, before the comment "#setting up the screen" would be OK.  Add the thread start somewhere before your main loop, perhaps where "c = 0", and then handle the extra event with your other event code.  Merging it in is not complicated.  Once you have it accepting 1 number, extend it to read two numbers at a time.